# SuperSearch with Keywords and Pagination

Tags: solspace, pagination, supersearch

Alright, trying to get SuperSearch with Keywords working with pagination. Having a bit of trouble, as the "autopath" variable isn't turning in to a useful URL.

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="products" limit="12" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
...
{paginate}
{if next_page}<a href="{auto_path}">Next</a>{/if}
{/paginate}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

This works fine without search terms:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/search/P12">Next</a>
```

However, a soon as I search:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/search&keywords=searchthing/P12">Next</a>
```

Which doesn't work as a URL, or to get the next page of keyword limited things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around.

With a template route of:

```
/search/{search:regex[(search\&.+)]}/{page:pagination}
```

And PHP-Output turned on, this solved my problem:

```
<?php
function FixPath($toFix)
{
    if (strpos($toFix, 'search/search') === FALSE && strpos($toFix, '&') !== FALSE) { $toFix = str_replace('search', 'search/search', $toFix); }
    return $toFix;
}
?>
{if previous_page}<a href="<?php echo FixPath('{auto_path}'); ?>">Previous</a>{/if}
{if next_page}<a href="<?php echo FixPath('{auto_path}'); ?>">Next</a>{/if}
```

Essentially, this simply looks for the undesired state, and fixes it. I had a combination of links sharing templates, so had to be careful how I fixed it.